# Router link changes the path but Router view doesn’t change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So i have a side navbar and some link in it. The entry point is the homepage. The problem is, when i'm trying to change router-view using router-link in my side navbar, the router-view doesn't change, but the path has change.

So here's my route path on my router.js:

```
        {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        children: [
                {
                    path: ':name',
                    name: 'theTask',
                    props: true,
                    component: TodoList
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ],
```

And here's my App.vue

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="main__content">
                <div class="sidenav">
                    <aside class="menu">
                        <ul class="menu-list">
                            <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'theTask', params: {name: 'today'} }">Today</router-link></li>
                            <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">Next 7 Days</router-link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

It rendered the homepage, but when i'm clicking router-link to the child route, it doesn't change the router-view, only the router link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real question is what is happening under the Hood.

### routes.js

```js
var routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home', // missed this one
    component: Home,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':name',
            name: 'theTask',
            props: true,
            component: TodoList
        }
    ]
}]
```

1. the parent is `Home` and the child is `TodoList` the route for parent is `/` and route for the child is `/:name`. you are trying to change the view true. and it's changing. But you can't see it. because there is no `router-view` in the parent of the component you are trying to change.

   By default, the parent is `App.vue` for every object in the routes array(if you don't change it otherwise).
   So `Parent` of component `Home` is `App.vue`. But the parent of `TodoList` is component `Home`. I am sure your `Home.vue` doesn't have `<router-view>`. When you are trying to render component `TodoList` it is rendering its parent and then finding `<router-view>` in its parent and trying to render itself there. But there isn't. And even if you add `<router-view>` in the `Home.vue` what you will have is both `Home` and `TodoList` rendering.
2. What I presume you are trying to do is to render `Home` and `TodoList` render separately on `App.vue` place. there are 2 options.

#### in `routes.js` file add 2 paths one for `/` and another for `/:name`

```js
var routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
},
{
    path: '/:name',
    name: 'theTask',
    props: true,
    component: TodoList
}];
```

#### have a base component(if you really need it) and add 2 children.

```js
var routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: Base,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: ':name',
            name: 'theTask',
            props: true,
            component: TodoList
        }
    ]
}]
```

Have a closer look at `Evan You`'s [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the use case but most likely you don't need to use `children` in your routes. That is meant for components that live ON the original page as their parent. If you just want a different component on a different page, you should define them as individual routes:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/:name',
  name: 'theTask', // although IMO this should be called something like "TodoList"
  component: TodoList
}
```

You can then use the Vue Developer Tools (for Chrome) to inspect and see which route is currently being rendered on your page.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should provide an empty subroute path. I have created a fiddle for the same [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sharitu/hny9vsup/3/). This is as per the `vue-router` [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

```
    { path: '/',
        component: Base,
      children: [{
        path: '',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
      },{
        path: ':name',
        name: 'theTask',
        props: true,
        component: Foo
      }]
    }
  ]
})
```